# MFC: Adding a status bar to a CDialogEx that is resizable?

Tags: mfc, statusbar, cdialog

I thought it be nice to add a Status Bar with percentage and other information to a `CDialogEx` that is used for viewing an image.  But it doesn't seem that you can simply use a `CMFCStatusBar` or a `CStatusBar` and have it just work.

I found various samples, but none of them have the statusbar outside the client area and moves as resized?   The different methods simply create a statusbar and it ends up hidden under a horizontal scrollbar and if you resize the window, the statusbar is sitting there in the middle of the dialog.

Is there an easy way or full example of having a statusbar on a `CDialogEx` that can be resized like a normal window?

Comment: A [status bar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/status-bar-reference) *is* a normal window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there an easy way or full example of having a statusbar on a `CDialogEx` that can be resized like a normal window?

Yes! Once you have created the status bar you can add it to the dynamic layout for resizing:

```cpp
//This is where we actually draw it on the screen
RepositionBars(AFX_IDW_CONTROLBAR_FIRST, AFX_IDW_CONTROLBAR_LAST,
    ID_INDICATOR_MEETING_TYPE);
GetDynamicLayout()->AddItem(m_StatusBar.GetSafeHwnd(),
    CMFCDynamicLayout::MoveVertical(100), CMFCDynamicLayout::SizeHorizontal(100));
```

I have a status bar (not `CMFCStatusBar` as it will not work, but `CStatusBar` is OK) on two dialogs in my application.

---

## When Dynamic Layout is not automatically enabled

Here is an updated example for when **Dynamic Layout** is not automatically enabled for you (`CDialogEx` with no controls):

```cpp
BOOL CMyDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
  CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();

  if (!m_StatusBar.Create(this)) {
    TRACE0("Failed to create status bar\n");
    return -1;
  }

  m_StatusBar.SetIndicators(indicators, _countof(indicators));

  RepositionBars(AFX_IDW_CONTROLBAR_FIRST, AFX_IDW_CONTROLBAR_LAST, 0);

  EnableDynamicLayout();

  auto pdlmanager=GetDynamicLayout();
  if (pdlmanager) {
    if (pdlmanager->Create(this)) {
      pdlmanager->AddItem(m_StatusBar.GetSafeHwnd(), CMFCDynamicLayout::MoveVertical(100), CMFCDynamicLayout::SizeHorizontal(100));
    }
  }
  // return TRUE unless you set the focus to a control
  // EXCEPTION: OCX Property Pages should return FALSE

  return TRUE;  
}
```

---

## Catering for horizontal scroll bars

NIf you have a **horizontal scrollbar** the StatusBar will end up **above it**; therefore you may have to create separate `CWnd` and add it to the dynamic layout (it would also be the `nIDLeftOver` of the `RepositionBars()`).

Here's how you can add the a "view" window for the contents so scrollbars can be contained within the view area:

```cpp
BOOL CMyDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
  CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();

  if (!m_StatusBar.Create(this)) {
    TRACE0("Failed to create status bar\n");
    return -1;
  }

  m_StatusBar.SetIndicators(indicators, _countof(indicators));

  CRect rc;
  GetClientRect(&rc);

  CString clsname=AfxRegisterWndClass(0);
  m_ImageView.Create(clsname, _T(""), WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, rc, this, IDC_MY_VIEW);

  RepositionBars(AFX_IDW_CONTROLBAR_FIRST, AFX_IDW_CONTROLBAR_LAST, IDC_MY_VIEW);

  EnableDynamicLayout();

  auto pdlmanager=GetDynamicLayout();
  if (pdlmanager) {
    if (pdlmanager->Create(this)) {
      pdlmanager->AddItem(m_StatusBar.GetSafeHwnd(), CMFCDynamicLayout::MoveVertical(100), CMFCDynamicLayout::SizeHorizontal(100));
      pdlmanager->AddItem(m_ImageView.GetSafeHwnd(), CMFCDynamicLayout::MoveNone(), CMFCDynamicLayout::SizeHorizontalAndVertical(100, 100));
    }
  }

  // return TRUE unless you set the focus to a control
  // EXCEPTION: OCX Property Pages should return FALSE

  return TRUE;  
}
```

Comment: I added additional information to answer that I needed to use to get Dynamic Layout enabled.

Comment: @df234987 Please try to keep my answer relative to your question. You are adding additional code outside the question of the status bar resizing. The first edit was ok about enabling the layout manager but the second edit is going in another direction IMHO.

Comment: Well, it gives the results people may want if using scrollbars.  You add the CStatusBar but doesn't quite give you want you really want and you need to add another item to encapsulate what used to be on the dialog - this way they get all the answers in one place.

Comment: @df234987 Ok 